# Using FOR loop to move files into another directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, scripting, directory

What I am trying to do:

1. Prompt the user to enter an account number.
2. The account number is the their folder.
3. The user is then prompted to select another directory (their time-stamped folder).
4. The script will then kick off an executable.
5. There will then be the parsing for `findstr` in a log file.
6. If the string comes back that it exists, then the script will then `goto` the `:move` sub-routine to attempt to `recursively` move through the "time-stamped" directory that the user selected to move all "*.ARC" files into their "Media1" folder.

The issue I am having is that the final step of running the `for` loop command in the "sub routine" `:move` is outputting the following error:

`The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

`The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

I'm not sure what is going on here as I can input this into a command prompt (without the `!variables!`) and get it to work. However, using the variables doesn't seem to work.

Another interesting point is that I am basically using the same `!variables!` under the `:string` "sub routine" and it finds exactly what I asked it to. So, I'm thinking there is nothing wrong with the `!variables!`?

Am I missing something here?

```
    :main

    cls
    echo.
    set /P acct=Please type the 9 digit account number you would like to restore: 
    set acctDir=x:\!acct!
    set acctDir2=media1\Setup\setup.exe /cd
    set log=c:\log.txt


    echo. Starting on !date! !time! on !Computername! >> !log!
    echo.
    echo The account number you selected is: !acct!
    echo.

    goto :user

:user

    set /p answer=Is this correct (Y/N)? 
    echo.

    if /i !answer!==y goto :yes (
    ) else ( 
        echo.
        echo Ok. Let's try again^^!
        echo.
        pause
        cls
        goto :main
        )
    )

:yes

    set c=0
    For /f %%a in ('dir !acctDir! /B /A:D') do (
    set /a c+=1
    echo !c!    %%a
    set dir!c!=%%a
    )

    echo. 
    set /p userIn="Select a directory [1-!c!]: "
    set userDir=!dir%userIn%!

    echo.
    echo You selected !userDir! for your data retrieval.
    echo.
    goto :string

:execute

    echo.
    echo The Data Protector Program will now be initialized...
    start !acctdir!\!userDir!\!acctDir2!

    goto :string


:string

    set sumLog=!acctdir!\!userDir!\SummaryLog.txt
    set succ=finished
    set acctDir3=media1
    set x=x:\!acct!\!userDir!

    findstr " .*!succ!" !sumLog!
    if exist errorlevel 0 (
        pause
        goto :move
    ) else (
        goto :eof
    )

:move


    for /r "!acctdir!\!userDir!\" %%g in (*.ARC) do echo move "%%g" "!acctdir!\!userdir!\!acctdir3!\"
    if exist errorlevel 1 (
        echo Cannot move files. Error occurred.
        pause
    )


endlocal
goto :eof
```

Comment: Can anyone shed some light on this situation?

Comment: Try echoing the delayed expansion variables before the for loop. `echo !acctdir!\!userDir!` - this will show you whether or not the variables are expanding to their correct values.

Comment: Great point! So I get the correct path with `!acctdir!\!userDir!\!acctdir3!\` with the following x:\101004357\Jan_20_2014_6_56_55_953PM\media1\. So, this tells me that the path is correct. So, how can I know if the syntax for the  `FOR` loop is working correctly?

Comment: Usually, there should be an error stating that access is denied or something to that affect. Not just display, "Press any key to continue..." for the `Pause` statement. I look in that directory and nothing is moved. Now, if I go and type everything into a command in command prompt, I get access denied. I know how to correct this, which isn't my issue. I'm trying to understand if the `FOR` loop will give me some kind of error output of some sort.

Comment: In the for command, add echo before the move so you can see what is going on. Also if `%%g` is already surrounded by quotes then doing `"%%g"` will not do what you want. You might need to try `"%%~g"` - the tilde removes surrounding quotes.

Comment: `for /r "!acctdir!\!userDir!\" %%g in (*.ARC) do echo move "%%g" "!acctdir!\!userdir!\!acctdir3!\"`

Comment: Nope. With that same FOR loop that you mentioned above still does not echo any output. Very odd, right?

Comment: This is what I get in CMD when I run the script. Press any key to continue . . .
x:\101004357\Jan_20_2014_6_56_55_953PM\media1\
Press any key to continue . . .
Press any key to continue . . . Then it just closes out.

Comment: What did you call the batch file?

Comment: RunExe.bat Everything else before it run without any issue. Think the name has something to do with it?

Comment: It's a newbie error when people call a batch file for example `move.bat` and when the batch file uses the `move` command - it launches the batch file again.   It didn't look like it in your case but I asked anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I definitely did not know that! But I will keep that in mind!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another tack to test your variables.

Add the four lines below after the `:move` label and run your batch file.
If there are any spaces or illegal characters you will see them there before the first pause.

```
:move

    echo "!acctdir!"
    echo "!userDir!"
    echo "!acctdir3!"
    pause

        for /r "!acctdir!\!userDir!\" %%g in (*.ARC) do echo move "%%g" "!acctdir!\!userdir!\!acctdir3!\"
        pause
```

Comment: The reason that I can't define these variables as new variables in this subroutine is because `acctDir` and `userDir` were input variables for the end user. They were defined in previous subroutines by end-user inputting information, which then assigned that input value to the variable. This was done so any account folder and subfolder can be selected. If you don't understand then I can attempt to explain more in depth. Thanks for the shot at it though!

Comment: I understand.  But you are telling us that the for command doesn't work.  This will either prove that the command works or it doesn't.

Comment: So if you check the code in my main question, I added an `IF` statement after the `FOR` loop. This is telling me that there is an error, but not sure exactly what the error is..... This is mind boggling to me because it should be so easy!! argh!!!!

Comment: Try my edited suggestion above. `if exist errorlevel 1` will not work.

Comment: I'm sorry that I forgot to mention that this isn't the full script. I only added partial to the script, but delayed expansion is enabled.

Comment: You aren't helping here.  Try my suggestion and see what is in the variables.  Your command is fine on visual inspection, so the variables must have an error or the drive or path doesn't exist.

Comment: This is the output I get: Press any key to continue . . .
"x:\101004357"
"Jan_20_2014_6_56_55_953PM"
"media1"
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: So this looks good to me. Not sure what could be causing this not to output any kind of error

Comment: I actually added another echo: echo !acctdir!\!userDir!\!acctdir3!\ and received the following output: Press any key to continue . . .
x:\101004357\Jan_20_2014_6_56_55_953PM\media1\
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Not sure if it's fair to point out, but this is a mapped network drive. The machine should treat the drive as if it's physically attached.

Comment: You haven't shown any output where it says `move "x:\path\filename.arc" "drive:\targetpath etc\"` and I don't know why.  The echo command in the for loop should always start with `move`.  if it does, then copy the command line you see with the move command and paste it into a cmd window as that is the command that must be failing, if the problem is indeed in the for loop.